# Linking lib in C++ project. VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, static-libraries

Sorry for this basic question :)

I have a very simple project with one cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>


int main() {
glfwInit();
return 0;
}
```

I added the path of .h file to proj-> properties-> C/C++-> Additional include directories

I added the path of .lib file to proj-> properties-> Linker-> General-> Additional Library Directories

I added the name of lib file to  proj-> properties-> Linker-> Input-> Additional Dependencies

But it doesn't work :(

I can't build theproject.

The error is :

"Error  1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwInit referenced in function _main    ...\OGL\first.obj   OGL "

What could be a problem ?

Thank you !

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Most likely, you added the wrong `.lib` file in the Linker's Additional dependencies.

Comment: NathanOliver, thanks.

CristiFati, How can I know which lib should I add exactly?  In other words how can I know what functions the specific lib contains?

Comment: You didn't write what 'the name of the lib' you used is - is it glew32.lib?  Does the bitness (32 / 64) of the one you link in match your executable?
One possible way to know which functions a lib implements is dumpbin /symbols.